# My own twist on the classic "Guessing Game" script in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, number-guessing-game

This is a (letter, or whatever the user decides to change it to) guessing game I wrote which implements both a mechanic to randomly change the order of elements in a list, as well as limit the number of attempts you get to complete the game. There's not much else to say about it. I'm just looking for some suggestions on where I can condense things and better optimize my code.

```
import random

samples = random.sample(['x', 'y', 'z'], 3)
keys = []

for i in samples:
    str(keys.append(i))

attempts_left = 3

print("X, Y, and Z are arranged in random order.")
print("The object of the game is to guess them in order before you run out of tries.\n")

while len(keys) > 0:

    for i, j in list(enumerate(keys, start=1)):
        key = j

        while attempts_left > 0:

            print("Round {}".format(i))
            guess = input("> ").lower()

            if guess == key:
                i += 1
                print("Correct\n")
                keys.remove(key)
                break

            elif guess not in ['x', 'y', 'z']:
                print("That's not one of the options.")

            else:
                print("Wrong\n")
                attempts_left -= 1

    if attempts_left > 0:
        print("You win!")
        break

    else:
        print("You LOSE!")
        print("Good DAY, sir!")
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the right functions**

What you want to do is present the string `xyz` in some order. For that, there's [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle). Doing sampling is for taking a small number of elements from a large set (think, drawing a poker hand from a deck), and is not well suited for this particular problem. So we can start with:

```
answer = 'xyz'
random.shuffle(answer)
```

Note that a string in python is also an iterable, you don't have to make it a list of strings. Also your `str()` in your loop does nothing - and the loop itself is just a very verbose copy. Just the `shuffle` suffices.

**Your outer loop**

Your logic looks like:

```
while cond:
    ...
    if cond2:
        break
    else:
        break
```

That is, the outer loop never matters. `len(keys) > 0` for sure the first time through and then we never check it again, so we can simply drop it.

**Iteration**

There's no reason to write `list(enumerate(iterable))` if you're just looping over it. That unnecessarily has to bring the *entire* enumeration into memory to construct the full list. You only need one element at a time - so let the iterable give you one element at a time.

We can also make this much more readable by naming things better:

```
for round, letter in enumerate(answer):
   ...
```

**Why are we enumerating anyway?**

Enumerating is for enumerating. But here, the round number doesn't actually correspond to the letter number. It should just be an external variable:

```
round = 0
for letter in answer:
    while attempts > 0:
        round += 1

        print 'Round {}'.format(round)
        guess = input('> ').lower()

        if guess == letter:
            print('Correct!')
            break
        elif len(guess) > 1 or guess not in answer:
            print('Invalid option')
        else:
            print('Wrong!')
            attempts -= 1
```

Comment: I don't understand your section about "Why are we enumerating?"

Comment: @200_success: Enumerating (from my understanding) is virtually the same as taking a list of items and creating an ordered list with a number before each element, except only Python sees the numbers. I was having a hard time getting the result I wanted (which was having the loop automatically increment each round after you successfully quess the key), so I just enumerated the list and assigned the numbers to 'j' in my for-loop. This allowed me to use it the same way as 'i'.

I'm assuming it's bad practice, so he's pointing it out.

Comment: @200_success The round we're on doesn't really correspond to the letter we're guessing. So `enumerate` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @BrandenM.Ardelean It's not "bad practice", it's just that you're not using the function for what it's meant to be used for.